# Get Subscriptions from Azure tenant using multi-tenant application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to build a multi-tenant application to retrieve all subscription information from my personal account.

Using the Powershell ARM I'm able to retrieve this information:

[image]

However, when trying to do this action using the azure management API:

> https://management.azure.com/subscriptions?api-version=2016-06-01

Using a JWT generated using my tenant, application id and key secret it returns the following:

> {"value": [] }

My application permissions seem fine:

[image]

Am I missing something from my permissions?

Edit: I am able to get my tenants using the same endpoint. Could this be something to do with my companies permissions for AAD users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,you'r using client credentials flow. With this flow, you cannot on behalf a user. **The Delegated permissions is not for this flow, it's for other on behalf user flow, like code grant flow.** So,you need to choose which one flow you need to use. If you still want to use client crendentials flow, you can take following steps to give it permissions:

You need to assign Role to your Service principal via [Azure RBAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-what-is).
Go to Azure portal > Select one specific subscription >  Access control(IAM) > Add > choose your service principal > select Contributor role  > Save

You can take same steps to add assign role to your sp from other subscription.

After doing this, you can have enough permissions to  use REST API via client credentials flow.
[image]

**About list subscriptions from other tenants:**

I didn't test this because I don't have mulitple subscriptions. But with multiple tenant APP, it also needs other tenant admin consent and assign role to it too.

With client credetials flow, you still can only get access token for one tenant. So, **you can only list subscriptions from one tenant once.**

## Update:

---

Even powershell actually gets subscriptions from other tenant from different teannt IDs many times. **So, you cannot use API to achieve that directly.**

I use Fiddler to catch the Traffic with Powershell running Get-azureRMsubscriptions:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help again Wayne. However, is there an alternative approach to this? I need to be able to collect other tenants subscriptions as my organisation has multiple tenants with specific subscriptions. 

As an example, the `Login-AzureRmAccount` and `Get-AzureRmSubscription` are able to get all tenant subscriptions. I'd like to be able to replicate this function. Is this possible? Without having to change the tenants AAD (Admin approval for the application is OK thought)

Comment: Note, using my method I am able to get tenants, wouldn't I have the same restrictions if my delegated permissions were not working?

Comment: Hi,@Dandy . I undesrtand your requirement. Based on my knowleage (I'm not 100% sure), Azure RM powershell also needs UI to login and get subscription as your account. But with client credentials flow, it cannot on behalf your account. This is the weakness for this flow. You need to accept it .Otherwise, you may need to use code grant flow instead it.

Comment: I'm trying the code flow option for just retrieving subscription data, I've managed to generate a token but this is now returning a 401 Unauthorized when trying to access the management API. The error is 'AuthenticationFailed'. Any thoughts? Thank you for all your help, I'll keep trying to figure it out in the meantime!

Comment: @Dandy  Code grant flow needs user to sign in action(interactive clients).Did you refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/#authorization-code-grant-interactive-clients) to configure?

Comment: Yeah thats how I've generated my token. However, its returning a 401. I'm still investigating. I'll check to make sure I've not missed some params in my request.

Comment: Hi,@Dandy . I have updated my answer, please check it. :-)