# Access to Multiple tenants on Azure AD using single sign on

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, azure-resource-manager

I have multiple tenants on azure. I want to access them using a single sign-on from my app. e.g I want to get all subscriptions related to all tenants by tenantId with a single hit. I tried the below api and it gives me one tenant information at a time. It requires the access_token for each tenant separately.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/subscriptions/get

I am able to get all tenant's information using (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tenants/list), but after that is there any option to pass the tenantId and get the other information like subscriptions and other detail based on passing tenantId.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide different access token for different tenants.

So it's impossible to list all the subscriptions for multiple tenants in one call.

PowerShell cmd [Get-AzureRmSubscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.profile/get-azurermsubscription?view=azurermps-6.13.0#examples) can list subscriptions for all tenants. But it still needs to get an access token for each tenant and then get it's subscriptions.

See a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49606141/get-subscriptions-from-azure-tenant-using-multi-tenant-application).

Comment: Allen Wu: Is there a way to get the access_tokens for all tenants one time? 
as if we will show the same login screen again and again to the user for different tenants, will not look nice.

Comment: @HarshGupta. Have you considered using client credentials flow (without user logs in)? See details in the last link in my answer. Note that as he said with client credentials flow, you still can only get access token for one tenant. So, you can only list subscriptions from one tenant once.

Comment: Yes that's the real problem. I don't want that customer will log in multiple times to get the access token for all tenants. Is there any other way, any SDK which can help to get access token for all tenants?

Comment: @HarshGupta, client credentials flow doesn't require a user to log in. As I asked above in my previous comment, is it an option for you? For SDK, I'm afraid there is no.

Comment: As per my understanding, Client Credentials flow will give the data only for one user. In my application actually any user can use a single sign-on option and see some specific information in our application.

Comment: @HarshGupta. Client Credentials flow means the data you can access has nothing to do with the user. As long as you assign role to your Service principal in every tenant, it can list all the subscription in all tenants. But if your users are in different tenants (for example, user a is in Tenant A and Tenant B, user b is in Tenant B and Tenant C), and you want user a to see subscriptions in Tenant A&B, user b to see subscriptions in Tenant B&C, Client Credentials flow will not work in this case. As I said above, there is no way to meet this requirement.

Comment: @HarshGupta Is there anything unclear about my answer?

Comment: Allen Wu: Your example is fine, we need the same solution. I am using msalService and some time it requires an access token for all and some times it doesn't. I am searching for why is it happening?

Answer (score 0):

This is achievable through Azure Lighthouse, but may not scale or be the correct solution depending on the scenario that your app is trying to fulfill.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/lighthouse/overview

This is mainly used by managed service providers to manage their Azure resources cross tenant, but you could also use it to manage your own internal Azure resources cross tenant.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/lighthouse/concepts/azure-delegated-resource-management

The managed services is comprised of two parts the definitions and assignment (you can kind of think of it similar to role assignment). The definition defines the tenant and users that will be able to see the other projections. The assignment gives the users and tenant defined in the definition access to the subscription.

How-To: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/lighthouse/how-to/onboard-customer

There are some limitations to this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/lighthouse/concepts/cross-tenant-management-experience#current-limitations