# How to authorize Azure multi tenant application to provision resources in customer tenant

Tags: python, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-authentication

I am building a multi tenant application and it has to provision few azure resources(resource group, even hub, storage hub etc) in customer(say target) tenant during a account setup process .

I followed the [azure doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant) to register an app . I can see the service principal created in target tenant under "Enterprise Applications" and this app has delegated type "azure service management API" permission .
[image: Application in target tenant]

**Question**:
I wanted to write an function app in source tenant(which is my tenant) in **PYTHON** which can fetch subscriptions/provision resources in target account . I tried `azure.identity.ClientSecretCredential` in function something like [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/azure-sdk-authenticate#using-clientsecretcredential-azureidentity) to fetch list of subscriptions  , it retuned **Zero** subscriptions . I think ClientSecretCredential doesn't fit for delegated type permission, until i add explicit role-assignment to the service principal , it wont have authorization . [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49606141/2653389) says the same .

Is it must to use `AuthorizationCodeCredential` , but it requires `auth_code` which needs user interaction . So, need to develop a web page which prompts for user consent and redirect the auth_code to this function using this function as redirect URI ?

Is there any other way ?
Any code reference would help .

Also, what is difference between `MSAL` and `azure.identity` package classes . Any documentation on this regard , when to use which API, I have seen various examples using either of them .

Comment: ClientSecretCredential uses client credentials flow. If you add explicit role-assignment to the service principal, you should be able to use `azure.identity.ClientSecretCredential`. What is the issue now? Why do you have to use `AuthorizationCodeCredential`?

Comment: @AllenWu as we don't have control over target tenant(it is the customer tenant) , can't use `ClientSecretCredential` . Basically I want to automate the customer account setup process like creating some azure resources etc .

Comment: Of course maybe you could use [`UsernamePasswordCredential`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-identity/azure.identity.usernamepasswordcredential?view=azure-python) to include the user token and delegated permission to list the information you want. But in this case the user also need to has access to the subscriptions/provision resources in target account. In another word, you also need to assign the corresponding RBAC role to the user (Corresponding to the service principal of `ClientSecretCredential`). Besides, UsernamePasswordCredential is not recommended by Microsoft.

Comment: `UsernamePasswordCredential` needs username, password of an admin of target instance, which I can't have . So, i can't UsernamePasswordCredential doesnt fit my usecase .  I guess `AuthorizationCodeCredential` is only way  and i have to expose an web page to let admin log into the my app and follow the auth code flow?

Comment: Also what is difference between `MSAL` and `azure.identity` package ? when to use which API ?

Comment: `AuthorizationCodeCredential` requires you to sign in interactively, I don't think it's feasible in function app. `UsernamePasswordCredential` doesn't require an admin of target instance. As I said above, you just need to assign RBAC role to the user. And one important point is that if you use `AuthorizationCodeCredential`, you also need to assign RBAC role to the user, not the AAD role (admin of tenant).

Comment: Learn about the differences from here: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/issues/299.

Comment: Thanks for the link , `UsernamePasswordCredential` we still need a user in target tenant user ,isn't it ?

Comment: Yes. It's the same as `AuthorizationCodeCredential`. Both of them require you to need a user in target tenant. The difference is: `AuthorizationCodeCredential` requires sign-in interactively while `UsernamePasswordCredential` not.

Comment: That is why I think `ClientSecretCredential` is enough. All the `Credential` requires you to assign RBAC role.

Comment: Let me try to rephrase my ques the function app would be in source tenant(tenant1) , the resources to be provisioned is in target tenant(tenant2) . i have control over tenant1(a tenant which will have the Saas application) .So, i have created a multi tenant application in tenant1 and this registered application client details can be used by the function app in tenant1, but I neither have access to create RBAC in tenant2 nor have user creds of tenant2, hope that clarifies

Comment: I totally understand your requirement. If you don't have a target tenant user (or the enterprise app (service principal)) who has been assigned RBAC role, you have no access to the subscriptions/provision resources because the lack of permission. Even though there is an app registration in their own tenant, it will require the RBAC operation I mentioned as well.

Comment: Agree to your point , I will rework on design and include auth code interactive flow  .And the prerequisite in our case would be the target tenant user who logs in should have RBAC for subscription level .

Comment: `AuthorizationCodeCredential` is not suitable for function app because it is impossible to implement interactive login in the function app according to my experience. But maybe I made a mistake, If you use `UsernamePasswordCredential`, it may be unnecessary to assign RBAC role. Adding the delegated permission is enough. Anyway, using `ClientSecretCredential` or `UsernamePasswordCredential` should be OK.

Comment: There is another method (another design), you can use [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) to get the access token for Azure Rest API in your front app and send the access token to your function, then call Azure Rest API in the function app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AuthorizationCodeCredential` is not suitable for function app because it is impossible to implement interactive login in the function app according to my experience.

Maybe you could use [`UsernamePasswordCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-identity/azure.identity.usernamepasswordcredential?view=azure-python), it may be unnecessary to assign RBAC role. Adding the delegated permission is enough. Anyway, using `ClientSecretCredential` (it's necessary to assign RBAC role to the service principal/enterprise app in this case) or `UsernamePasswordCredential` should be OK.

In short, if you want to use user token (`AuthorizationCodeCredential` or `UsernamePasswordCredential`) to call Azure Rest API, you need to know (or enter) the credentials of the target tenant user.

Other design: you can use [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) to get the access token for Azure Rest API in your front app and send the access token to your function, then call Azure Rest API in the function app.

You can learn about the differences between `MSAL` and `azure.identity` package from [this post](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/issues/299).